# Can we Append a Series to a Field in a Data Frame, from another Data Frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I created a series from my first data frame, like this.

```
myResult = df_append['schedule_code']
```

Now, I want to add that series to a second data frame, as such.

```
grouped_and_summed['schedule_code'] = myResult
```

The result is all NANs.

[image]

The `'myResult'` field is a simple code, which was parsed into the first data frame.

[image]

I can't seem to parse it into the second data frame, and I can't seem to copy it from the first data frame.  There must be able to get a variable, and fill down everything in one field, right.  Any thoughts, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using pandas version 1.0.1 and that seems to be allowed. If you run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
# Generate data
df1_data = list(range(1,11))
df2_data = list(range(11,21))
# Create dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1_data, columns = ['data_df1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2_data, columns = ['data_df2'])
df2['new_col'] = df1['data_df1']
print(df2)
```

You should see the following output:

```
    data_df2    new_col
0   11          1
1   12          2
2   13          3
3   14          4
4   15          5
5   16          6
6   17          7
7   18          8
8   19          9
9   20          10
```

I believe that is equivalent to performing a left join on each dataframe index (if each consisted of only one column, that is, since pandas Series are indexed objects). If you try changing the index of one of those dataframes, say df1:

```
import pandas as pd
# Generate data
df1_data = list(range(1,11))
df2_data = list(range(11,21))
# Create new index
new_index = list(range(1,11))
# Create dataframes and apply new index to df1
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1_data, columns = ['data_df1'], index=new_index)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2_data, columns = ['data_df2'])
df2['new_col'] = df1['data_df1']
print(df2)
```

You should see the following result, as the new df1 index starts at 1, while df2's still starts at 0:

```
    data_df2  new_col
0        11      NaN
1        12      1.0
2        13      2.0
3        14      3.0
4        15      4.0
5        16      5.0
6        17      6.0
7        18      7.0
8        19      8.0
9        20      9.0
```

So ideally, this kind of task would be best performed using df.merge, instead of directly attributing a column from one dataframe to another, but if you're absolutely sure that your dimensions match in each of the dataframes, and both dataframes are ordered in such a way that you will get the desired output by simply copying from one and pasting in the other, you can either:

1. reset the indices, by doing:

   ```
   grouped_and_summed.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
   df_append.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
   grouped_and_summed['schedule_code'] = df_append['schedule_code']
   ```
2. Use the .values attribute to get an array of values instead of an indexed Series:

   ```
   grouped_and_summed['schedule_code'] = df_append['schedule_code'].values
   ```

Again, I'd highly recommend using df.merge if possible for consistency purposes.